# radiogroup not supported in Angular2 - template parse errors

Tags: angular, angular2-template, radio-group

**The Context**

I've got an Angular2 app for which accessibility is important. The accessibility evaluator I'm using is complaining when radio inputs have the same name, but are not enclosed in a `radiogroup` element. But when I do put a `radiogroup` element, Angular2 gives template parse errors:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'radiogroup' is not a known element:
1. If 'radiogroup' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'radiogroup' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<div>
  [ERROR ->]<radiogroup>
    <input type="radio" name="foo id="true" label="True" value="true" />
    <in"): App@2:6 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error:
```

**The Code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <radiogroup>
      <input type="radio" name="my-radio" value="true" />True
      <input type="radio" name="my-radio" value="false" />False
    </radiogroup>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {};
```

I have imported `FormsModule` into the module.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ftmNXs1kNiU3SBm1Gmkr)

Comment: Please find a radio group module for angular2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-radio-group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`radiogroup` is not a standard HTML element, it is an attribute which is used like below, ([Check this PLunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/98ODt1MA6BmcoXkY4svv?p=preview))

```
    <div> 
      <input type="radio" radiogroup="alignment" name="my-radio" value="true" />True
      <input type="radio" radiogroup="alignment" name="my-radio" value="false" />False
    </div>
```

If you are creating a component  named `radiogroup` you need to declare it in NgModule before using it,

**Update**

You can add a directive without template so that Angular does not complain about unknown elements, and it will work with [**XUL**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL) based application for building user interfaces of applications like Firefox.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'radiogroup'
})
export class RadioGroupDirective {  }
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZZN5b10N0KYA47WPElP?p=preview)!

I have not tested above in Firefox, so not sure if you would get all a[ttributes, properties and methods of radiogroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radiogroup) or not, ideally it should work.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks! I had been going by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radiogroup which suggests it can be used as an element.

Comment: @A.Duff: Updated answer, Cheers